# Can the occupation of Floquet bands be calculated from the Keldysh Green's function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions, non-equilibrium

A periodically driven band structure can be semiclassically described by [Floquet theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory), resulting in photon-dressed Floquet bands (non-equilibrium steady states). Usually, for non-equilibrium systems, we use the non-equilibrium Green's function obtained in the Keldysh formalism. Under certain circumstances, if one can fully calculate the Keldysh Green's function of the Floquet Hamiltonian, how does one calculate the occupation of the Floquet bands?